# Why does an error occur when decompiling through Uncompyle6

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is an exe of the compiled python file 3.9 version.
exe is 100% packed by pyinstaller

Decompiled exe, moved 1 line from abc.pyc to main.pyc Launched uncompyle6, gave an error

`AttributeError: module 'xdis.opcodes.opcode_39' does not have attribute 'END_FINALLY'`

Tried decompyle3 the same error. Who knows how to fix it?

Comment: Which _specific_ Python 3.9.x created the bytecode? Which _specific_ version of xdis is trying to read it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy xdis==5.0.9, python 3.9.5

Answer (score 1):

Support for Python 3.9.5 is added in xdis 5.0.10; it is not available in 5.0.9.

Comment: Here is the full error log
https://pastebin.com/QLnRUC6a

Comment: Per https://github.com/rocky/python-xdis/blob/af8c0f1cd5694adc945a208c7655b30f791914f4/xdis/opcodes/opcode_39.py, `END_FINALLY` no longer exists -- "removed since 3.8". Are you sure this is _really_ 3.9.5 bytecode?

Comment: yes, so the error is in the uncompyle6 itself?